# Let $f(x,y) = y + x\sin(\frac{1}{y})$ if y $\neq 0$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ if $y = 0$. Show that the double limit equals $0$ but the iterated limits DNE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Been struggling with this one for a bit now, I know there's something simple I'm overlooking but I can't quite figure it out.

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}y+x\sin(\frac{1}{y}) & y\neq0\\ 0 & y=0 \\ \end{cases}$

a) Show that $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0$ but $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}$ $\lim \limits_{y \to 0} f(x,y)$ does not exist. 
I think that I can show $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0$ by breaking it into the sum of two limits. 
Then I would have $0 + \lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x\sin(\frac{1}{y})$ which I think would be $0$ by squeeze theorem.

Another approach I tried was to assume that $f(x,y)$ is continuous and evaluate directly with $x,y=(0,0)$ and then show that the two iterated limits don't exist by evaluating at $0^+$ and $0^-$ but that didn't seem appropriate.

Essentially, I am stuck on how to show that the double limit at the end doesn't exist, because I feel like it should by the same logic as the double limit. I'd really appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already proved that the double limit is $0$ using squeeze theorem.  Your proof is correct.

For the iterated limit to exist $\lim_{y \to 0} [y+x\sin (\frac 1 y)]$ must exist for all $x$ in some interval around $0$. Fix any non-zero $x$ and show that the limit does not exist. For this look points at which $\sin (\frac 1 y)=1$ and points at which $\sin (\frac 1 y)=-1$ specifically, the points $\frac 1 {2n\pi+\frac {\pi} 2}$ and $\frac 1 {2n\pi+\frac {3\pi} 2}$.